# How to open command prompt as administrator from address bar

Tags: windows, cmd

I use address bar of File explorer to open command prompt in current directory(By typing cmd in address bar). It will open the command prompt as Administrator. I have used Windows 7 OS and I logged in as Domain Administrator.

Now I upgraded the OS to Windows 10. Now I am doing the same, But command prompt is not opened as Administrator.(For local Administrator account it was fine). Is there any way to get command prompt as Administrator(Opening from Address bar) ?

Comment: This interesting anomaly seems like it could be interpreted as a security problem. To get to the address bar, you have to press Ctrl-D or click into it, then type "cmd". Wouldn't it be even easier to press the Start key and type "cmd"?

Comment: @Liturgist the advantage on typing it into the adreesbar is, that it will start in the current directory.

Comment: Yes, probably your UAC was deactivated on Win 7. But This question seems to better fit to Super User SE. I can't see any programming relation.

Comment: Not a stackoverflow question.

Comment: This question came up as an answer to my question - how to open cmd to the currently open folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Screenshot for achieving cmd in Admin mode]

We can add this windows default shortcut for achieving cmd as Administrator in single click

Comment: Unfortunately, this was removed at some point :(

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately a recent Windows 10 Update has removed the Open command prompt mentioned by @Arvindharaj.  However, if you feel comfortable editing the Windows Registry then this site that explains how to [activate admin cmd right-click option](https://www.maketecheasier.com/open-command-prompt-file-explorer-windows/) might be a great option.  It was for me.

Here are basic steps after launching `regedit.exe`:

1. Go to this address: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell`
2. Under this folder create a new key and label it `runas`.
3. Double-click the `runas` folder and check if there’s a “Default” key. Right-click it and choose “Modify.”
4. Once you click “Modify,” the “Edit String” box shows up.  Type `Open Administrator Command Prompt Here` in the Value data box.
5. Next, in the same folder, create a new string value (right-click the `runas` folder and choose New and select String Value). Label it as `NoWorkingDirectory`.
6. Under the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas` path, create another key and label it as `command`.
7. Double click the folder and you’ll see the Default string value. Right click and choose “Modify.” Under the Value data, enter `cmd.exe /k cd %1` and click OK.

FYI - I think this last step is wrong btw.  The cmd prompt will launch as admin but in its default folder.  So instead enter "cmd.exe /s /k pushd %V" and this should launch the admin prompt in the folder you right-clicked on.

Comment: Please include the relevant contents from your link in your answer. Links can become broken at any time.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried @Alex's solution, but it still didn't work, CMD still evaluated without Administrator privileges.
I only have it working after running the following command in command prompt:

```
> REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
/v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

And restart the Computer after this.

Can't say that this only helps, but maybe this in addition to @Alex's did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Adding up to response from Aravindharaj G :

1> In File Explorer go to the window where you want to open PowerShell / Command Prompt
Use `HotKey  ( ALT (Hold) + F > S > A  )`  will open PS in that location.

2> Using Top Menu File > Open Command Prompt ( or Open Window PowerShell ) > Open Command Prompt as Administrator > now SELECT

> "Add to Quick Access Toolbar"

This will add a Tiny icon in all File Explorer Windows for all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, and solved it as follows:

File Explorer's address bar recognizes all .exe and .bat files (and other extensions within the PATHEXT environment variable) that are in path environment variable.

In a directory that is in the path environment variable, e.g. %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps, create a .bat file, e.g. cmdadm.bat with the following content:

```
set here=%cd%
wscript.exe "C:\...\helper.vbs" "C:\Users\sbo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe" %here% "Command Prompt"
```

As you can see, you'll need a helper.vbs file (courtesy of https://github.com/lextm/windowsterminal-shell)

helper.vbs:

```
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
     executable = WSCript.Arguments(0)
     folder = WScript.Arguments(1)
     If Wscript.Arguments.Count > 2 Then
         profile = WScript.Arguments(2)
         ' 0 at the end means to run this command silently
         shell.ShellExecute "powershell", "Start-Process \""" & executable & "\"" -ArgumentList \""-p \""\""" & profile & "\""\"" -d \""\""" & folder & "\""\"" \"" ", "", "runas", 0
     Else
         ' 0 at the end means to run this command silently
         shell.ShellExecute "powershell", "Start-Process \""" & executable & "\"" -ArgumentList \""-d \""\""" & folder & "\""\"" \"" ", "", "runas", 0
     End If
```

Now you can simply type cmdadm in the File Explorer address bar and you'll get a Command Prompt as administrator in the current directory.

- wt.exe stands for Windows Terminal
- "Command Prompt" is the Windows    Terminal profile, which is present by default